# Update a table with values from itself, but selecting on criteria from a different table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a junction table that only consists of foreign keys like so:

```
 JUNCTION
+-------+-----------+---------+---------+
|  id   | module_id | comp_id | ins_id  |
+-------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1     | 1         | 2       | 8       |
| 2     | 2         | 4       | 9       |
| 3     | 3         | 4       | 10      |
| 4     | 4         | 1       | 10      |
| 5     | 3         | 5       | 11      |
| 6     | 4         | 1       | 11      |
| 7     | 5         | 42      | 11
+-------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

One of the referenced tables is `modules` like so:

```
 MODULES
+-----------+---------+---------+
| id        | name    | version |
+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1         | default | 1       |
| 2         | bar     | 1       |
| 3         | foo     | 1       |
| 4         | foo     | 3       |
| 5         | foo     | 2       |
+-----------+---------+---------+
```

Is there a way in SQL to update this table so that the `comp_id` for the junction id `4` in the junction table gets updated to `comp_id 4` (the same name as module 3, but a greater version), and junction id `6` gets comp_id `42`, which is the `comp_id` of the preceding module version (2), because they have matching module **names** and **ins_id**, and so on for all records that have this same criteria?

In prose: 
Update all module references having comp_id 1 in the junction table, updating them with the comp_id of a module that has a matching module name, setting it to the comp_id of the module with the next smallest version, and matching `ins_id` (and can be constrained by other columns in the junction table)

Or, would this be better handled programmatically, in business logic?

Comment: I don't understand how the comp_id and module_id are related. Once you find the "right module" how do you know which comp_id to use?

Comment: It would be the comp_id associated with the “right module” from the junction table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've solved it: The answer is [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/tutorial-window.html) (although some combination of joins might be able to do it. I was getting close, but thought this would be more elegant and understandable)

First, I had to create a CTE that would map the module name and version to the values in the junction table:

```
WITH module_mapping AS (SELECT j.module_id, j.ins_id, j.comp_id, m.name, m.version
   FROM junction AS j
   JOIN modules AS m ON m.id = j.module_id
)
```

with that CTE, I could then create a window function that would select the records with the same module :

```
, win AS (SELECT name, version, module_id, ins_id, comp_id, first_value(comp_id) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY name, ins_id ORDER BY version DESC
     ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
   FROM module_mapping)
```

So, when I make the following query, I can see that the `first_value` column has the records I'm looking for:

```
WITH module_mapping AS (SELECT j.module_id, j.ins_id, j.comp_id, m.name, m.version
       FROM junction AS j
       JOIN modules AS m ON m.id = j.module_id
    )
, win AS (SELECT name, version, module_id, ins_id, comp_id, first_value(comp_id) 
OVER (PARTITION BY name, ins_id ORDER BY version DESC
     ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) -- this key part excludes the current row, since it will have the largest (newest) module version
   FROM module_mapping)
SELECT * FROM win WHERE comp_id = 1;

+-------+---------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+
| name  | version | module_id | ins_id | comp_id | first_value |
+-------+---------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+
| "foo" | 3       | 4         | 10     | 1       | 4           |
| "foo" | 3       | 4         | 11     | 1       | 42          |
+-------+---------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+
```

So with these two CTEs, I could call my update sql:

```
UPDATE junction AS j
SET comp_id = win.new_comp
FROM win
WHERE j.comp_id = 1 -- only change the default ones
AND j.module_id = win.module_id
AND j.ins_id = win.ins_id;
```